# Reporting services 2008: ReportExecution2005.asmx does not exist

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to generate a report directly from the code (to send it by mail after). I make this in a windows service.

So here is what I'm doing:

```
Dim rview As New ReportViewer()

Dim reportServerAddress As String = "http://server/Reports_client"
rview.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri(reportServerAddress)

Dim paramList As New List(Of Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter)
paramList.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("param1", t.Value))
paramList.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("CurrentDate", Date.Now))

Dim reportsDirectory As String = "AppName.Reports"
Dim reportPath As String = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", reportsDirectory, reportName)

rview.ServerReport.ReportPath = reportPath
rview.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramList) 'This is where I get the exception

Dim mimeType, encoding, extension, deviceInfo As String
Dim streamids As String()
Dim warnings As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Warning()

deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo><SimplePageHeaders>True</SimplePageHeaders></DeviceInfo>"

Dim format As String = "PDF"

Dim bytes As Byte() = rview.ServerReport.Render(format, deviceInfo, mimeType, encoding, extension, streamids, warnings)
```

When debugging this code, I can see it throws a `MissingEndpointException` where I make the `SetParameters(paramList)` with this message:

> The attempt to connect to the report
>   server failed.  Check your connection
>   information and that the report server
>   is a compatible version.

Looking in the server's log file, I can see this:

> ui!ReportManager_0-8!878!06/02/2010-11:34:36::
>   Unhandled exception:
>   System.Web.HttpException: The file
>   '/Reports_client/ReportExecution2005.asmx'
>   does not exist.    at
>   System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath,
>   Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath,
>   Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath)
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebServiceParser.GetCompiledType(String
>   inputFile, HttpContext context)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext
>   context, String verb, String url,
>   String filePath)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext
>   context, String requestType,
>   VirtualPath path, String
>   pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) 
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

I didn't find any resource on the web that fits my problem.  Does anyone have a clue ?  I'm able to view the reports from a web application, so I'm sure the server is running.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nevermind, I was confused with servers names...

Instead of using

`http://server/Reports_client`

, I just needed to use

`http://server/ReportServer_client`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Reporting Service Configuration Manager]

I have attached reporting server configuration manager screen shot and highlight the Reporting server integration URL